# Trying to use soemthing from a const into a class in react

Tags: reactjs

i'm actually trying to use "use history" in my class, but it's somehow "stuck" in the const, and I have no ideas on how I can use it outsite of the said, const.
here's the class:

```
class QrContainer extends Component<{}, { result: string}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            result: 'c\'est la folie',
        }
        this.handleScan = this.handleScan.bind(this)
    }

    handleScan(result){
        this.setState({
            //result: history.push("/ProfilEleve"),

            result
        })
    }
```

and here is the start of the const,

```
const ProfilAdmin: React.FC = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([])

const history = useHistory();
```

Comment: show some code like what you have done till now

Comment: paste this code in your question in a readable format.

Comment: Are you trying to do a setState that holds a function to use it later? If so you are actually doing it the wrong way, you need to pass the reference of that function and then execute it later on your code.